# std::result_of doesn't work on functor which operator() has rvalue argument in visual studio 2012

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, c++11, rvalue-reference, result-of

Here simple example:

```
#include <type_traits>
int foo() {
    return 2;
}
struct A {
    int operator()(int&& x) {
        return x*2;
    }
};
int main(int, char**) {
        std::result_of<A&(int)>::type x = 42;
        return 0;
}
```

When i try to compile it in VisualStudio 2012 I get an error:

```
error C2664: 'int A::operator ()(int &&)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'int' to 'int &&'
You cannot bind an lvalue to an rvalue reference
```

I compile same code in mingw-g++ and everything work fine.
Can I do anything rather than write my own result_of realization? (I wrote it as workaround).

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a bug in the implementation of `std::result_of` or `std::declval<>()`.

Paragraph 20.9.7.6 (Table 57) of the C++11 Standard specifies that the following must hold for `result_of`:

> If the expression
>   `INVOKE(declval<Fn>(),
>   declval<ArgTypes>()...)` is well
>   formed when treated as an
>   unevaluated operand (Clause 5), the
>   member typedef `type` shall name the
>   type
>   `decltype(INVOKE(declval<Fn>(),
>   declval<ArgTypes>()...));`
>   otherwise, there shall be no member
>   type.

In this case, `INVOKE(declval<A&>(), declval<int>())` resolves to invoking an lvalue of type `A` with an rvalue of type `int` (see paragraph 20.8.2/1).

Considering the call operator of `A`, the member typedef `type` shall resolve to `int`.

Answer (score 1):

Inheriting the functor from std::unary_function seems to resolve this bug of VS2012